# Which classes should have access to a ViewModel

Tags: android, database, android-intent, android-activity, android-room

I'm wondering what is a good/best practice to deal with ViewModels and multiple Activities referring to a specific piece of data in my database.

Assuming I have a FriendViewModel which provides access to my friend_database (throught a Repository and a Dao of course) and a RecyclerView displaying all FriendEntities.

If I now want to edit a friend in a different Activity: is it better (or more efficient) to pass one or more FriendEntities (implementing Serializable) to the intent, or should I rather pass the friendId + FriendViewModel and retrieve the FriendEntity from the friend_database using the passed FriendViewModel and friendId?

As this seems to be a common scenario: is there a best practice for that situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We usually have separate ViewModels for different Activities/Fragments unless we have common data we want to handle and that's where SharedViewModel comes into play. In your situation, I don't see using a ShareViewModel necessary at all.

FirstActivity:

`ListActivity -> ListViewModel -> FriendRepository -> FriendDao`

SecondActivity

`EditActivity -> EditViewModel -> FriendRepository -> FriendDao`

So the only things shared here are your **Repository** and **FriendDao** which wraps around Friend model.

Pass **friend id** from ListActivity to EditActivity, ask FriendRepository to retrieve that friend by using DAO.

That's the approach I personally use and most of the samples out there will use.

Comment: This approach is especially usefull when navigating back and forth my activities using 
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(), because the parent activity relied on Entities to be passed to it. Saves a lot of time passing all sorts of extras that could easily be retrieved from the DB every time they are needed.